# Angularjs: trying to create a dynamic dropdown from json

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Thanks in advance, trying to create dynamic dropdown as per application requirements. according to the right side value, the dropdown list will show from a single json. just like [screen shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ1Ti.jpg). 
Also added my fiddle. `http://jsfiddle.net/subhamoy/jq964fph/22/`.
I am just creating a dummy in my fiddle where I am only creating this using html. Please suggest me how to modify the below json to make this view.

```
{  "User_Id": "3542871f-e233-4e81-ac7c-ab8219ae65c4",
  "attributes": {
    "Total_Current_Assets": [
      "Total Current Assets",
      "Other Current Assets",
      "Total Assets",

    ],
    "Interest_Cover_Ratio": [
      "Interest Cover RatioLatest",
      "Interest Coverage",
      "Interest Coverage Ratio",
      "DSCR",
      "Interest Earned",

    ],
    "Rating": [
      "Controlling Company credit risk rating (Borrower level)",
      "Final Rating",
      "Facility Amount",
      "StockHolder Equity_RAC",

    ],
    "ROCE": [
      "ROCE (%)Latest",
      "Capital Employed",
      "Operating Profit Before Working Capital Changes CF",
      "Total Asset Turnover RatioLatest",
      "Adjusted PAT",

    ],
    "ModelID": [],
    "Secured_Loans": [
      "Other Debt",
      "Gross Interest Expense",
      "Is the Borrower a Subsidiary?",
      "Senior Long-Term Debt",
      "Subordinated Debt",

    ],
    "ModelRunID": [],
    "Total_Shareholders_Funds": [
      "Total Equity",
      "StockHolder Equity",
      "StockHolder Equity_RAC",

    ],
    "Total_Debt__Loan_Funds": [
      "Total Debt",
      "Interest Income   Total Funds (%)Latest",

    ],
    "Tax": [
      "Total Income",
      "Net Income Before Tax and Extraordinary Items",
      "Current Liabilities and Provisions ( Incl  Def  Tax)",
      "Other Long Term liabilities",
      "Net Income Before Tax and Extraordinary Item",

    ],
    "RONW": [
      "Operating Profit Before Working Capital Changes CF",
      "ROCE (%)Latest",
      "StockHolder Equity",
      "StockHolder Equity_RAC",
      "Debt Equity Ratio",

    ],
    "Adjusted_Net_Profit": [
      "Adjusted PAT",
      "Total Income",
      "Special (Income) Expense",
      "Operating Profit Before Working Capital Changes CF",
      "Other Non Operating Long-Term Liabilities",

    ],
    "Sundry_Debtors": [
      "Other Non Operating Long-Term Liabilities",
      "Intercompany Non Current Liabilities",
      "Intercompany Current Liabilities",
      "Other Non Operating Current Liabilities",

    ],
    "Inventories": [
      "Inventory",
      "Value Of Output",
      "Change in Other Non-Current Assets and Investments CF",
      "Days Inventories (avg)",

    ],
    "Total_Current_Liabilities": [
      "Total Current Liabilities",
      "Short-Term Borrowings",
      "Other Non Operating Long-Term Liabilities",
      "Other Non Operating Current Liabilities",

    ],
    "Customer_ID": [],
    "Sales_Turnover__Operating_Income": [
      "Sales",
      "Operating Income   EBIT",
      "Non-Operating (Income) Expense",
      "Other Non-Operating (Income) Expense",

    ],
    "Interest": [
      "Interest Coverage",
      "Total Income",
      "Interest Cover RatioLatest",
      "Other Income",
      "Current Deferred tax Liabilities",
      "DSCR",

    ],
    "Total_Income": [
      "Total Income",
      "Other Income",
      "DSCR",
      "Specific Income",

    ],
    "Operating_Profit": [
      "Operating Profit Before Working Capital Changes CF",
      "Total Income",
      "Adjusted PAT",
      "Interest Coverage",
      "Interest Earned",
      "Interest Cover RatioLatest",

    ],
    "Debt_Equity_Ratio": [
      "Debt Equity Ratio",
      "Total Equity",
      "Total Assets",

    ],
    "Net_Sales": [
      "Net Sales",
      "Net Income Margin",
      "Total Revenues_RAC",

    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON does not need to be modified, it is OK.  You'll want to use `ng-repeat` and `ng-options`.  What have you tried?  Your fiddle doesn't properly bootstrap Angular nor the controller, and doesn't show any attempt at template code.

Comment: @sh0ber Thanks for the answer. Please check this fiddle link 
   [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/subhamoy/w8kt0b1s/1/)

Comment: in your fiddle, you used ng-option as supposed to ng-options... it is working against the data in your fiddle

Comment: @Alqbal yes It's working. Thank you.